# $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2, G)$ and $G\times G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

Let $G$ be a finite, not necessarily abelian group, and let $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^n, G)$ describe the set of group homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Z}^n\rightarrow G$.

I have been tasked with describing $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,G)$ as a subset of $G\times G$. I read this as trying to find a bijection between $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,G)$ and a subset of $G\times G$.

My first thought was to look at the isomorphism between $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G)$ and $G$; since $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}$, we have $\phi(1)\in G$, which seems to give rise to an isomorphism between the two structures. However, after doing some reading, it seems that this is only true if $G$ is abelian.

If this kind of thinking *does* work, then I might be able to extrapolate using the fact that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ generate $\mathbb{Z}^2$. However, I'm not convinced it does. Any suggestions/things to read would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},G)\ni f\mapsto f(1)\in G$ is bijective regardless of the fact that $G$ is abelian. $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}^2,G)\ni f\mapsto (f(1,0),f(0,1))\in \{(g_1,g_2)\in G\times G\,|\,g_1g_2 = g_2g_2\}$ is bijective,

Comment: @Slup, thanks for the response!

Comment: No problem. There is a typo in my comment. I should have written $\{(g_1,g_2)\in G\times G|g_1g_2 = g_2g_1\}$.

Comment: Yea, I figured that's what you meant.